# display: inline-block pushes my divs downwards

Tags: html, css, web

My problem is that i'm trying to get three entirely independent columns and with 'display: inline-block', my columns get side by side but starts under the biggest.

HTML, CSS:

```css
.container > div {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
  <div>
    aaaaaaa<br>bbbbbb
  </div>
  <div>
    cccccc<br> ddddddd<br>eeeeeee
  </div>  
    <div id="end">
      ffffff
    </div>
  </div>
    
</body>
```

The problem is that the smallest line is aligned to the last line of the biggest div, as follows: [image: The ffff is not right]

Comment: this has been answered so many times on SO, try searching first then question afterwards

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with inline-level and table cell elements, the `vertical-align` property applies. The initial value of this property is `baseline`. That's what you're seeing. The text in each box is aligned to the baseline. Adjusting the `vertical-align` property to another value (such as `top`) solves the problem.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, although i don't think it's the best way to do this:

```
.container > div {
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

:)

Comment: I think this is the best way to do this. Why the uncertainty? What else would you suggest?

Comment: This is the common way to line up inline-blocks by their top border, don't worry.

Comment: Idk, i'm just never satisfied. Thanks, guys

Answer (score 0):

You could add css property vertical-align: top, that way all content will start at the top of the div.

```css
.container > div {
 display: inline-block;
vertical-align:top
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
  <div>
    aaaaaaa<br>bbbbbb
  </div>
  <div>
    cccccc<br> ddddddd<br>eeeeeee
  </div>  
    <div id="end">
      ffffff
    </div>
  </div>
    
</body>
```

Comment: Yeah, just tried that. Thank you!

Comment: I would suggest you to check into flex property in order to handle columns width in a responsive environment. This guide is awesome: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/